# Download file from another server using curl

Tags: php, file, curl, download

i am trying to download a remote file using curl i tested this code in different files and servers and it was working fine,but it does not work here

```
$ch = curl_init();
$targetFile = fopen( 'FindchipsExport.xls', 'w' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.findchips.com/mySearchListToExcel?distributors=1567');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $targetFile );
curl_exec( $ch );
fclose( $targetFile );
```

Comment: "not working" is horribly vague, please add specific details about the problem you're having, and add some error reporting code - see [the curl_error doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) for some inspiration.

Comment: no curl error appear ,i mean by here for this url http://www.findchips.com/mySearchListToExcel?distributors=1567

Comment: Your url returns `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`. If you use without UserAgent, then it returns `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` to new location `http://www.findchips.com/findchips/contact.jsp?distributors=1567`.